# Selecting online users from db with mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, time, timer

I use this code to update the user database with the latest time when the user was online:

```
$postTime = $user_array['last_online']; 

if ($postTime == ""){
  $minutes = 11;
} else {        
  $now = time();
  $seconds = $now - $postTime; // $seconds now contains seconds since post time
  $minutes = ceil($seconds / 60); // minutes since post time
  //$hours = ceil($minutes / 60); //hours
}   

if ($minutes > 10) {
  $con = db_connect2(); 

  $sql = "UPDATE tbl 
             SET last_online='".strtotime("now")."' 
           WHERE userid='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userid']). "'"; 
  mysql_select_db('db',$con);
  $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);                 
}
```

I am not sure if thats the best way to do it, but I think it works. Now I want to get all the users that have been active within the last 10 minutes with a mysql command. Is this possible. Something like

```
$time = time() - 600;
$online = $conn->query("select username 
                          from tbl 
                         where last_online < $time");
```

Comment: It gets people who were online OVER ten minutes ago, which isn't the desired result (we want users online LESS THAN ten minutes ago). See my answer.

Comment: For the `$online` query make `<` -> `>=` as Dustin Fineout pointed out below. That is, instead of `... last_online < $time ...` use `... last_online >= $time ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the original post actually loads users who were online more than ten minutes ago, rather than within (less than) ten minutes. So, instead of checking whether `last_online` is less than ten minutes ago, we want to check whether it is greater than ten minutes ago.

```
$time = time() - 600;
$online = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM tbl WHERE last_online >= $time");
```

Answer (score 2):

As your table is populated with more and more users this sort of query will become very slow. I'd recommend creating a new table like `online` or `recent_users` and whenever a user refreshes the page INSERT/UPDATE a row within that table. Periodically delete rows from the `online` table that have a timestamp older than 10 minutes.

Time is not a good column on which you may have an index, but year, month, day is. Good luck!

Comment: Why add all this overhead? What is wrong with a timestamp (integer) as an index? It's numeric comparison - sort doesn't get much easier.

Comment: What's wrong is that they're almost all unique. Think of index as a phonebook page cutout for your thumb. If you index on something that is not grouped - it's not very useful because searching the index takes as long as searching the actual data (unless it's a literally unique index or primary key)

Answer (score 1):

use `SELECT username from tbl where last_online >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)`

Comment: I update last_online with strtotime("now") but the query return an an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: Try updating with `last_online=NOW()`

Comment: Why use extra functions and push the subtraction onto the MySQL server? See my answer for a more efficient solution.

Comment: @Dustin - that's getting a bit ridiculous.  The sql server can handle the subtraction just fine.  I've used the same type of query many times and it works just fine.  ganjan's just doing a poor job of explaining the problems he's running into.

Comment: Of course it can handle a simple subtraction, the point is WHY would you load extra work onto the database server? I personally try to optimize every interaction, i.e. not making extraneous function calls, doing arithmetic in-app rather than within a WHERE clause, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this (assuming you are storing the last_online data as unix timestamp):

```
select username from tbl where last_online < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-600)
```

Comment: This also loads user who were online greater than ten minutes ago, rather than within the past ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have one situation here and I think can help.

Actually I use a table `acessPermission`, on this table I have the columns `Id, Ip, Page, Date`.

My column `Date` is a type `DateTime` when I need t know in my reports about the access I had, I just retrieve the column `Date` from the database and I explode apart the time, and I compare like this:

**Date from database**

```
$exp=explode(" ", $date);
$exp[0]; // here I have the date
$exp[1]; // here I have the time
```

**Today**

```
$today = date("H:i:s"); //I have the time
```

**Subtract the dates**

```
$subt = ($exp[1] - $today);
```

The result is the subtraction of the hour only, you need to convert in a timestamp the result and compare it again I think, or you need to check the date, after the hour, after the minutes..

**Now compare the time**

```
if ($subt<600) {
 block intructions
} else {
 block intructions
}
```

I hope this can help a little.

Good Luck